# Запись в БД

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой код:

---

```
  while ( ($data_f = fgetcsv($handle_f, 1000, ";"))!== FALSE) {
$insert_q = 'insert into test (val1,val2,val3,val4) values '.
  '("'.$data_f[0].'","'.$data_f[1].'","'.$data_f[2].'","'.$data_f[3].'")';
@mysql_query($insert_q);
```

---

Можно ли запрос в базу данных переделать таким образом, чтобы вместо одиночного инсерта был групповой?

Comment: @Neek05, не нужно нажимать "наградить" по любому поводу! Достаточно нажать "палец вверх" и, если ответ вас полностью устраивает, то галку напротив него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `test` (`val1`,`val2`,`val3`,`val4`) VALUES ";
$data = array();
while ( ($data_f = fgetcsv($handle_f, 1000, ";"))!== FALSE) {
  $data[] = "(".$data_f[0].",".$data_f[1].",".$data_f[2].",".$data_f[3].")";
}
$query .= implode(',', $data);
```

$query содержит весь запрос. Остаётся его только выполнить. А если будете использовать устаревшее расширение для работы с БД "**mysql_***", то придёт суровый [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto) и поставит в угол. ;) Используйте MySQLi или PDO.

Comment: Интересует такой вопрос:
У нас есть файл с расширением csv (размер может быть как большим, так и малым). Нужно его распарсить и записать в БД. Правильнее будет записывать одиночному селекту или Ваш вариант более рационален?

Comment: @Neek05, для ваших целей. на мой взгляд, лучше бы использовать [LOAD DATA INFILE][1]

   [1]:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html